# Ошибка при попытке вывести часть словаря, который в списке

Tags: python, api, response

Текст ошибки:

> TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable

может слишком много кода прикрепил, но надеюсь не зря

```
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import os.path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

def install_pictures(filename, url):
    filename = f"images/{filename}"
    response = requests.get(url)

    response.raise_for_status()
    Path("images").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        file.write(response.content)

def install_pictures_nasa(api_key):
    response = requests.get("https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod", params=api_key)
    response.raise_for_status()
    for index, images in enumerate(response["hdurl"]):
        install_pictures(f"images_{index}.svg", images)
    return response.json()


load_dotenv()

api_nasa_token = os.getenv("API_NASA")
api_nasa = {"api_key": f"{api_nasa_token}", "count": "30"}

print(install_pictures_nasa(api_nasa))
```

полный код ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\demon\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(install_pictures_nasa(api_nasa))
  File "C:\Users\demon\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 34, in install_pictures_nasa
    for index, images in enumerate(response["hdurl"]):
TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34509116/4711135

Comment: Попробуйте взять `response.json()["hdurl"]`